# How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^3\cdot \frac{42n+5}{2^{12n+4}}=\frac1\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

In an article about $\pi$ in a popular science magazine I found this equation printed in light grey in the background of the main body of the article:
$$
\color{black}{
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^3\cdot \frac{42n+5}{2^{12n+4}}=\frac1\pi
}
$$
It's true, I checked it at [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e1tr5t2jans), who gives a even more cryptic answer at first glance, but finally confirms the [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eo719ptcghc).

The appearance of $42$ makes me confident that there is someone out there in this universe, who can help to prove that?

Comment: A similar expression, but based upon [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity), would be this: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!}\right]^2=\frac4\pi$$

Comment: The simple approach would be to learn black witchcraft and summon Ramanujan from the dead.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: +1 Hahaha. Awesome comment.

Comment: A complete proof is provided in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4015012/72031).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a famous identity of Ramanujan in ["Modular equations and approximations of $\pi$"](http://books.google.com/books?id=QlbzjN_5pDoC&pg=PA254).
There is a proof by the Borweins in ["Pi and the AGM"](http://books.google.com/books?id=UynfQwAACAAJ) (no preview) p. $177$ to $188$ (this proof and others are rather long!).

UPDATE:
["Ramanujan’s Series for 1/π: A Survey"](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/monthly567-587.pdf) provides the history of the subject with all the technical details.
The brothers Borwein proposed a derivation in $1987$ in ["Ramanujan's rational and algebraic series for $\dfrac 1{\pi}$"](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P36.pdf).
Guillera proposed different ["Kind of proofs of Ramanujan-like series"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.1255) in $2012$.

A proof 'by computer' using the [WZ algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) may be found in the paper of Ekhad and Zeilberger ["A WZ proof of Ramanujan's formula for $\pi$"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9306213).
[Aycock](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.1140v2.pdf) proposes to compute many similar series using hypergeometric identities like (page $6$ and $28$) :
$$_3F_2\left(\frac12,\frac12,\frac12,1,1,x\right)=(1-x)^{-1/2}\;_3F_2\left(\frac14,\frac34,\frac12,1,1,-\frac{4x}{(1-x)^2}\right)$$

Comment: Hi Raymond. Thanks for the links (+1). What a collection by Aycock, wow! This at least gives a hint for the appearance of $_3F_2(\cdots)$ in Wolframs solution. I just scanned the pages you recommended, but do you think that a proof would fit into a single post here? The Zeilberger paper looks promising...

Comment: @draks: I am looking at the Borweins book now (not sure I'll be able to 'condensate' the thing...). Perhaps that others will have better answers in the meantime, cheers !

Comment: If not I'll dedicate a bounty to Archimedes on his $2310^{\text{th}}$ birthday...

Comment: @draks: note that Ramanujan's derivation is short (equation $(29)$ of the first link) at least for people knowing elliptic functions...

Comment: @draks: I added clearer references (without finding a short 'independent' derivation sorry...)

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\large\tt Hint:$
$\ds{%
{1 \over \pi}
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bracks{\pars{2n}! \over \pars{n!}^{2}}^{3}
{42n + 5 \over 2^{12n + 4}}
=
{21 \over 8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}^{3}n\pars{2^{-12}}^{n}
+
{5 \over 16}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}^{3}\pars{2^{-12}}^{n}\,,
\qquad{\large ?}}$
Let's consider the function
$\ds{{\cal F}\pars{x} \equiv \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}^{3}x^{n}}$ and we
have to evaluate
$\ds{\braces{\bracks{{21 \over 8}\,x\,\partiald{}{x}
+ {5 \over 16}}{\cal F}\pars{x}}_{x = 2^{-12}}}$ $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{this expression returns the value}\ {1 \over \pi}~}}$:

> \begin{align}
> {\cal F}\pars{x} &\equiv \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}\int_{\verts{z_{1}} = 1}
> {\dd z_{1} \over 2\pi\ic}\,{\pars{1 + z_{1}}^{2n} \over z_{1}^{n + 1}}
> \int_{\verts{z_{2}} = 1}
> {\dd z_{1} \over 2\pi\ic}\,{\pars{1 + z_{2}}^{2n} \over z_{2}^{n + 1}}\int_{\verts{z_{1}} = 1}
> {\dd z_{1} \over 2\pi\ic}\,{\pars{1 + z_{3}}^{2n} \over z_{3}^{n + 1}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \prod_{i = 1}^{3}\pars{\int_{\verts{z_{i}} = 1}
> {\dd z_{i} \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z_{i}}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> x\pars{1 + z_{1}}^{2}\pars{1 + z_{2}}^{2}\pars{1 + z_{3}}^{2}
> \over
> z_{1}z_{2}z_{3}}^{n}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \prod_{i = 1}^{3}\int_{\verts{z_{i}} = 1}
> {\dd z_{i} \over 2\pi\ic}\,
> {1 \over
> z_{1}z_{2}z_{3} - x\pars{1 + z_{1}}^{2}\pars{1 + z_{2}}^{2}\pars{1 + z_{3}}^{2}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Ah, [***42***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) and *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*. Would you like to know how this is connected to the ***24***-dimensional ***Leech lattice***? :)

Given the Ramanujan-type formula,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^3\cdot \frac{An+B}{(C)^{n+1/2}}=\frac1\pi$$

there are relatively simple expressions for $A,C$. Define,

$$A(\tau) = \sqrt{d\big(C(\tau)-64\big)}$$

and the **24**th power of the [Weber modular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_modular_function) as,

$$C(\tau) = \mathfrak{f}^{24}(2\tau)=\left(\frac{\eta^2(2\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\eta(4\tau)}\right)^{24}$$

with the [Dedekind eta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindEtaFunction.html),

$$\eta(\tau) = q^{1/24} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{n})$$

The [connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function#Definition) between the appearance of ***24*** in $\eta(\tau)$ and the Leech lattice is quite well-known.

**Example:** Let $\tau = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-d},\; d = 7$, then,

$$A(\tau) =4\cdot42$$

$$C(\tau) = 2^{12}$$

$$e^{\pi\sqrt{7}} \approx 2^{12} - 24.06\dots$$

$$\frac{4(42n+B')}{(2^{12})^{n+1/2}}$$

so,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\right)^3\cdot \frac{42n+B'}{2^{12n+4}}=\frac1\pi$$

hence why, using a ***24th*** power of an eta quotient, the number [***42***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) appears.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4015012/72031) for Ramanujan's proof.